# Is $C(X,S)$ $\sigma$-compact ($X$ compact, $S$ is a complete metric space)?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, stochastic-processes

Suppose $X$ is a compact metric space and $S$ is a complete separable metric space. Let $\mathcal{C}(X,S)$ be the space of all continuous functions from $X$ into $S$. Prove that $\mathcal{C}(X,S)$ is $\sigma$-compact.
(I read this statement on Kallenberg's book *Foundations of Modern Probability*, where it is stated as a consequence of Arzela-Ascoli's theorem. A proof of this escapes me.)

Comment: This is not true is $S$ is not $\sigma$-compact, since the subset of $C([0,1],S)$ of constant maps is isometric to $S$ (and closed).

Comment: Why mention $[0,1]$ and then go to $X?$

Comment: It seems that the statement is false and that this is an errata on page 308 of Kallenberg's book on foundations of probability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is false: Suppose $C([0,1],\mathbb R)= \cup K_n, n \in \mathbb N,$ where each $K_n$ is compact in $C([0,1],\mathbb R).$ Now $C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ is a complete metric space, so by Baire, some $K_n$ has nonempty interior. But any open ball in $C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ contains a countable set of functions whose distances from each other are greater than some fixed positive number. That violates compactness.

Comment: That confirms that the statement is wrong on the cite above. Thanks.

Comment: Does the separability of $C(K,S)$ claimed in Kallenberg hold then?

Comment: @Uchiha See the answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46011/is-the-space-of-continuous-functions-from-a-compact-metric-space-into-a-polish-s

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with that book, but it seems likely it holds. It certainly holds in my example.